# Asp.net Identity tool after publishing to iis or smartasp.net wont work

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, web-applications, identity

[error photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDFCy.jpg) Hello. I making my first website.Visual studio.For authentication i use Identity tool. In localhost it work fine i can reach everything, but after publishing it to iis or smartasp.net i cant enter login and register pages.Other pages work good. When i click login it show http error 500 This page isnt working right now. Localhost cant currently handle this reąuest.

> Someone maybe had the same issue? It looks like i have to do something with identity because i can enter other pages.
> Maybe before publish i have to change something?
> First i make publish to iis. Login page got that error. I took maybe problem in iis. Than i used smartasp.net but the issue is same

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please share more details and codes. What .net version you are using? What is your configuration code? ....

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, you can open developer mode in the browser, open network tab, reproduce the error, check for useful information, and you can also use failed request tracking to see details about 500 error.